# Resgatar o index de um objeto com certo atributo dentro de um array de objetos

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho o seguinte em javascript:

```
var listaImagens = [{"idImagem":4,"arquivo":"illustration_transport-04.svg","idCategoria":1,"nomeCategoria":"Transportes","modificacoes":[{"id":"sxqae3wtj1h2rzfr","cor":"#ff6500"},{"id":"egltjnqi7ut2zkt9","cor":"#FFFFFF"},]},{"idImagem":5,"arquivo":"casa.svg","idCategoria":2,"nomeCategoria":"Construcoes","modificacoes":[{"id":"aksjdhauhkuhksee","cor":"#fcdd10"},{"id":"lasdweiefnswekej","cor":"#FFCD00"},]};
```

Como faço para encontrar o index do objeto que possui "idCategoria" = 2.

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
indexes = $.map(listaImagens, function(obj, index) {
    if(obj.idCategoria == 2) {
        return index;
    }
})

firstIndex = indexes[0]
```

Fonte SO gringo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997879/get-the-index-of-the-object-inside-an-array-matching-a-condition

Answer (score 3):

Uma opção que eu adotaria:

```
var indice = listaImagens.indexOf(listaImagens.filter(function(obj){
    return obj.idCategoria == 2;
})[0]);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ruipimentel/cfLmLrex/

### 1. Explicação

#### Função filter() [ [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) ]

Está disponível em todo Array. Recebe como primeiro parâmetro uma função; esta função é chamada de **callback**, e é executada (pela função `filter()`) uma vez para cada elemento do array. A função `filter()` tem como saída o próprio array, porém *filtrado*.

A função de callback é quem realiza esta filtragem, returnando `true` (manter) ou `false` (cortar) para cada elemento do array. Tal função baseia-se em **até 3 parâmetros** (abaixo) para esta escolha, mas no meu caso escolhi receber da função `filter()` apenas o primeiro:

- *[Obrigatório]* elemento atual do array (no meu caso, `obj`);
- *[Opcional]* índice deste elemento no array;
- *[Opcional]* uma referência ao array sendo percorrido;

No meu exemplo, fiz com que apenas os elementos com a condição `obj.idCategoria == 2` retornassem `true` e, portanto, eliminei os demais elementos do array.

#### Função indexOf() [ [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) ]

Esta função nos retorna o índice de um elemento dentro do array. Para tal, ela determina, de maneira estrita (`===`), a igualdade do parâmetro informado com cada elemento do array. No caso de objetos literais, como é o caso aqui, a comparação estrita só retornará `true` caso o parâmetro seja uma *referência* a um elemento do array. Por este motivo, foi necessário a realização da filtragem (`filter()`) e da seleção do primeiro elemento do array pós-filtragem (`[0]`).

### 2. Resolução deste problema em um futuro próximo

O futuro nos reserva um método ainda mais prático de descobrir o índice de um elemento dentro de um array. O Firefox foi o primeiro a correr na frente e implementar **uma função proposta no ECMAScript6, chamada de `findIndex()`**, e também disponível no protótipo do Array [ [Array.prototype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) ].

Ela funciona de maneira muito semelhante às funções `map()` e `filter()`, recebendo uma função de callback como parâmetro que será executada em sequência por cada elemento do array; assim que uma execução da callback retornar `true`, o índice do elemento será retornado pela função `findIndex()`.

Desta maneira, o código poderia ser reduzido ainda mais para:

```
var indice = listaImagens.findIndex(function(obj){
    return obj.idCategoria == 2;
});
```

Lembrando, mais uma vez, que a implementação desta **função não foi concluída na maior parte dos browsers**, inclusive nas últimas versões do Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) ou [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) do array. A vantagem da primeira é que você pode pegar o item completo:

```
var auxIndex = -1;

// com filter
var item = listaImagens.filter(function(i, idx) {
    if(i.idCategoria == 2) {
        auxIndex = idx;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
})[0];

// com forEach
listaImagens.filter(function(i, idx) {
    if(i.idCategoria == 2)
        auxIndex = idx;
});
```

Nas duas funções, `i` é o elemento atual e `idx` é o índice do mesmo.